# Birth year uses and meaning

Tags: multiple-regression

the paper name is "THE COGNITIVE EFFECTS OF MICRONUTRIENT DEFICIENCY: EVIDENCE FROM SALT IODIZATION IN THE UNITED STATES", in this paper there was a salt iodine reform on 1924 and the authors want to check how it influences the intelligence of the cohorts after this reform. to do that they check scores from army test for ww2. they estimate the model using lpm model and in their estimation they include many fixed effects , my question is regarding -birth year fe , they check the score test of enlistment to Air Force in ww2 ( 1940-1945) but they control for the birth year of those future enlistments (1920-1928) , I am having problem what those birth year fe control for.
thanks

Comment: Can you provide any context?  Can you provide a complete citation & link to the paper?  What were the data?  What were the research questions? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the problem we want to solve and the amount of dat, birth year can be used as a discrete variable (for cohort grouping), similar to gender, or can be used to calculate age which is a continuous variable.

Comment: the paper name is "THE COGNITIVE EFFECTS OF MICRONUTRIENT DEFICIENCY: EVIDENCE FROM SALT IODIZATION IN THE UNITED STATES", in this paper there was a salt iodine reform on 1924 and the authors want to check how it influences the intelligence. to do that they check scores from army test for ww2. they estimate the model using lpm model and in their estimation they include state fe , but also birth cohort fe